# Using curl with xargs connection hanging sometimes - any way to retry?

Tags: bash, curl, xargs, http

```
echo $LIST | xargs -I{} -n 1 -P 8 sh -c 'curl -o backup.dump http://url.com'
```

I am running this for a large amount of files (around 300). After a while, sometimes curl hangs and won't progress for a file. This is problematic because these are all important database dumps. Is there anyway to automatically reset or restart the hanging transfer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of timeout and retry options:

```
curl --max-time <seconds> --retry <num>
```

`--max-time` is total time for getting the file.

`--retry` starts new attempt after either connection error or the timeout.

You might also consider `--connect-timeout`, `--retry-max-time`, and `--retry-delay` options. See `man curl` for details.